# Use assignable type for RefObject in React with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am using React with Typescript and Material UI. I want to pass a ref as a props. In WidgetDialog I have

```
export interface WidgetDialogProps {
   ....
    ref?: React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>;
}

....

<div data-id={dataId} className={classes.dialog} ref={ref}>
       --- dialog content ---          
</div>
```

And when I want to use it in other component :

```
 const canvasRef = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

 <WidgetDialog
     ref={canvasRef}
     ....
  >
....
</WidgetDialog>
```

I am geting this type error:

```
Type 'RefObject<HTMLDivElement>' is not assignable to type '(string & RefObject<HTMLDivElement>) | (((instance: Component<WidgetDialogProps, any, any> | null) => void) & RefObject<...>) | (RefObject<...> & RefObject<...>) | undefined'.
  Type 'RefObject<HTMLDivElement>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<Component<WidgetDialogProps, any, any>> & RefObject<HTMLDivElement>'.
    Type 'RefObject<HTMLDivElement>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<Component<WidgetDialogProps, any, any>>'.
      Type 'HTMLDivElement' is missing the following properties from type 'Component<WidgetDialogProps, any, any>': context, setState, forceUpdate, render, and 3 more.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(107, 9): The expected type comes from property 'ref' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<WidgetDialogProps, any, any>> & Readonly<...> & Readonly<...>'
```

What is the correct type for ref in interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that `ref` is a reserved property, and the error happens because the `WidgetDialog` tries to consume it. Try to change the property name to something else, such as:

```
export interface WidgetDialogProps {
   ....
    rif?: React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>;
}

....

<div data-id={dataId} className={classes.dialog} ref={rif}>
       --- dialog content ---          
</div>

 const canvasRef = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

 <WidgetDialog
     rif={canvasRef}
     ....
  >
....
</WidgetDialog>
```

See also: https://alligator.io/react/createref/

Comment: Not working:

Type '{ children: (false | Element)[]; data-id: string; className: string; ruf: RefObject<HTMLDivElement> | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>'.
  Property 'ruf' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>'.  TS2322

    58 |             onClose={onClose}
    59 |         >
  > 60 |             <div data-id={dataId} className={classes.dialog} ruf={ruf}>

Comment: but this time is "does not exist"! did you change the interface signature as well?

Comment: Yes. I added it to WidgetDialogProps interface